# Which PhP framework to use for building My Own CMS

Tags: php

I am new to Php and I ll be working for a fresh project in my company. Have been learning PHP from last 2 months.  The project is much more about creating a CMS in PHP. I have not worked before for a project using PHP. However I have worked with Python and Django. Now I am looking for a sugestion from experienced people in PHP, which framework i should use or shell I start creating this project on Core PHP. Framework is not a bar in my organization. What will be the best effort for my learning. I am willing to put endless efforts to learn.

Comment: You can use your time better learning to use a ready-to-use CMS. PyroCMS is easily hack knowing codeigniter, which is a PHP framework very approachable to a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should know that all php frameworks are fundamentally flawed in one way or another. bad design choices, fake OOP ( like cake and ci ), magic.

My advice would bie , if you have your own framework - use it .. it will be a nice test if nothing else. If you really want to use a ready-made framework , then try looking at Symfony2 or Kohana3. They are the less-messed-up ones right now.

Comment: I agree with this post, i've tried countless time to switch to an open framework such as cake, symfony, etc only to be rebuted by the complexity of learning "their ways". Most of the time, too much magic is included into it or on the other side, too much configuration. Building your own framework will be the best solution if you want to go all the way to creating your own CMS. Good luck...

Answer (score 2):

I was writing a response, but Mathieu answered before me ; it was the same idea : those days, it will be more usefull for you to learn using and modifying existents CMS than to make your own. And you can do your best to understand the mechanisms behind, and improve your PHP skills. ;)

And if one day you need a CMS for your project, I suggest Symfony2. Strong framework, a lot of possibilities and very recent so we'll need a lot of Symfony2 experts soon.

Answer (score 1):

While it may sound strange, why is your company trying to build a CMS when you already have very strong CMS already present on the market that feature a plethora of pluggins or even more, a good documentation on creating pluggins that can fufill practically anything you want.

I was an evangelist of Joomla a few months back, but my new job showed me how to work with Wordpress and i know that Silverstripe is a serious contender coming nicely along.

I'd look at the projects available before building a new CMS, there is a lot of work to do in that direction...

Comment: U know, Mine is a small company, and its the clients requirement. Can't argue with my boss On this..lollzzz

Comment: Small company or not (i work in a 12 employee company which by all means is small too) you have to act as a IT professionnal and say to your client that creating a whole new CMS will cost 100x than using one already there and with all the bugs and headaches of testing to come i don't see how the client would absolutely want to go down this road... If he did with me, i'd probably tell him to go see elsewere, problems ahead!

Answer (score 1):

If you worked with Django have a look at [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

Comment: Working with laravel, it's structure is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

You have added cakephp as a tag yourself, so why not go ahead and build a CMS with that? I'd say go for it!

Answer (score 0):

If you know MVC then you can use cakephp framework to build your CMS. Cakephp provides you bake command to build you modules fastly.